# Java doesn't download full file

Tags: java, http

I have a little problem with downloading file from HTTP server. The code below downloads only ~30MB of file(file size is 52MB). My browser download file without any problems. What is wrong?

```
URL website = new URL("http://www.website.com/information.asp");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("information.html");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
```

Comment: Post the rest of the source code.  Where are you closing the stream?

Comment: You need to close the file stream so it flushes any buffers.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a flushing issue.

Comment: I added fos.close(); after fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24); and the problem still exists.

Comment: (1 << 24)/1024/1024 = 16 Mbyte

Comment: how we set utf-8 encoding in this file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[FileChannel.transferFrom()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom%28java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long%29) Java documentation says:

> Transfers bytes into this channel's file from the given readable byte
>   channel.
>
> An attempt is made to read up to count bytes from the source channel
>   and write them to this channel's file starting at the given position.
>   An invocation of this method may or may not transfer all of the
>   requested bytes; whether or not it does so depends upon the natures
>   and states of the channels. Fewer than the requested number of bytes
>   will be transferred if the source channel has fewer than count bytes
>   remaining, or if the source channel is non-blocking and has fewer than
>   count bytes immediately available in its input buffer.

```
URL website = new URL("http://www.website.com/information.asp");
URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel( connection.getInputStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("information.html" );
long expectedSize = connection.getContentLength();
System.out.println( "Expected size: " + expectedSize );
long transferedSize = 0L;
while( transferedSize < expectedSize ) {
   transferedSize +=
      fos.getChannel().transferFrom( rbc, transferedSize, 1 << 24 );
   System.out.println( transferedSize + " bytes received" );
}
fos.close();
```

Comment: There's nothing in Eclipse's console. How to check it in other way? wget downloads full file.

Comment: The program finished normally without problems.

Comment: What's printed as ExpectedSize?

Comment: Size of file on server in bytes.

Comment: you, know - "An attempt is made to read up to count bytes from the source channel and write them to this channel's file starting at the given position."
public abstract long transferFrom(ReadableByteChannel src, **long position**, long count)  working code: http://pastebin.com/qZS4c973

Answer (score 0):

```
        try {

        InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(inputStream);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("your-pc-path");

        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```